# Tornado: Is the RequestHandler.on_finish() method guaranteed to be called?

Tags: python, tornado

As the title asked: Is the `RequestHandler.on_finish()` method guaranteed to be called? Even if, say, the `.post()` method had an unhandled Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `on_finish` is always called even when an unhandled exception occurs.

Tornado runs the handler method within a `try...except` block. So when there's an unhandled exception, Tornado generates a 500 error response and calls the `finish()` method to close the request which in turn calls the `on_finish()` method.